# Discrete groups acting on hyperbolic space

Tags: group-actions, hyperbolic-geometry, isometry, reflection, coxeter-groups

I am interested in groups of isometries which act discretely on uniform spaces of constant curvature, ie $\mathbb{S}^n$, $\mathbb{E}^n$, and $\mathbb{H}^n$. I believe I am right that any such group acting on $\mathbb{S}^n$ or $\mathbb{E}^n$ can be realised as a finite index subgroup of a discrete group generated by reflections (a finite or affine Coxeter group respectively).

**Question:** can any discrete group $G$ of isometries acting on $\mathbb{H}^n$ be realised as a finite index subgroup of a Coxeter group acting on $\mathbb{H}^n$?

On the one hand, any isometry of $\mathbb{H}^n$ can be decomposed as a sequence of reflections, so intuitively one could take a set of generators for $G$ and replace any which are not reflections be a set of suitable reflections, but *a priori* it is not clear that the resulting group will be discrete. On the other hand we know from the classification of irreducible hyperbolic Coxeter groups, that they only exist in dimensions $3,\dots,10$ which suggests there may be discrete groups of isometries acting essentially on $\mathbb{H}^n$ for $n>10$ which aren't subgroups of Coxeter groups.

An explicit answer would be great, but alternatively a specific reference where I can find the answer would be useful. I'm pretty sure this isn't answered in Humphreys, Bourbaki, or Brown for example.

Comment: What does the phrase "be realized" mean in your question? Are you asking whether $G$ is **equal to** a finite index subgroup of a Coxeter group? Or are you asking whether $G$ is **isomorphic to** a finite index subgroup of a Coxeter group?

Comment: @LeeMosher I mean is equal to. So for example the group $\mathbb{Z}^2$ acting on the Euclidean plane by translating up/down and left/right can be realised/is equal to an index 4 subgroup of $D_\infty\times D_\infty$, similarly [this tiling of $\mathbb{H}^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane#/media/File:Snub_triheptagonal_tiling.svg) is a subgroup of index 2 (I think) of the triangle Coxeter group $(2,3,7)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your claim that every discrete group of isometries of $\mathbb E^2$ is equal to a finite index sugroup of a Coxeter group is not true. One can infer this from a dimension count, as follows.

Let's consider the space of discrete groups $\Gamma$ of isometries of $\mathbb E^2$ with the following properties:

1. $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$,
2. $\Gamma$ is normalized (up to conjugation by a similarity) to contain the translation $T_{(1,0)}$, meaning that $T_{(1,0)}(x,0)=(x+1,y)$, and so that $T$ has minimal translation length amongst all elements of $\Gamma$.

This space is 2-dimensional, as you can see by noticing that there exists an element $T_{a,b}$ in the group (meaning that $T_{(a,b)}(x,y)=(x+a,y+b)$) such that $(a,b)$ is contained in the region defined by the inequalities $a^2+b^2 \ge 1$ and $0 \le a \le 1$, and furthermore this element is almost unique: $\Gamma$ contains at most 2 such elements $T_{(a,b)}$, and 2 of them occur only if $(a,b)$ lies on the boundary of the region, meaning that $a^2+b^2=1$ or $a=0$ or $a=1$.

The Coxeter triangle groups are all rigid up to normalization, and so their finite index subgroups form a countable subset of the space of discrete groups.

The only Coxeter groups that are not triangle groups are the rectangle reflection groups, and they form just a 1-dimensional space. Their finite index subgroups therefore form a 1-dimensional subset of the space of discrete groups, namely those for which there exists some element of the form $T_{(0,b)|$, $b \ge 1$. Your up/down, left/right example in your comment does lie in this subspace.

Using this analysis, for an explicit example that is not a finite index subgroup of a Coxeter group, take the group generated by $T_{(1,0)}$, $T_{(1/2,1)}$.

---

A similar dimension count applies to discrete groups of isometries of $\mathbb H^2$. This gets into the topic of hyperbolic surfaces and hyperbolic 2-orbifolds and their Teichmuller spaces. I'll give just the simplest example (which is already too complicated to describe in full detail, so I'll have to leave a lot of claims unproved). Consider the abstract group $\pi_1(S_2)$ which is the fundamental group of the closed oriented surface $S_2$ of genus $2$, defined by the presentation
$$\pi_1(S_2) = \langle a,b,c,d \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1} \rangle
$$
This group has a Teichmuller space, which is the space of (suitably normalized) discrete subgroups of isometries of $\mathbb H^2$ that are isomorphic to $\pi_1(S_2)$. One can do a dimension count to show that this space is 6-dimensional. Also, the Euler characteristic of $S_g$ is equal to $\chi(S_g)=2-2g$ in general, and $\chi(S_2)=-2$.

If $\pi_1(S_2)$ is isomorphic to a finite index subgroup of a Coxeter group, then the corresponding reflection polygon $P$ has a rational Euler characteristic $\chi(P)$ which is a rational number strictly between $-2$ and $0$. These reflection polygons can be explicitly enumerated, and the dimensions of their Teichmuller spaces all calculated explicitly, and one sees that in each case the dimension is strictly less than $6$.

Comment: Fabulous answer, thank you! In your Euclidean counter example we can conjugate by an affine transformation to make it a subgroup of $D_\infty\times D_\infty$, and something similar can be done in the hyperbolic case? This is what you were driving at in your comment about the meaning of "realised as". When you said "isomorphic to" I was thinking as completely abstract groups rather than in this more restrictive sense. Is my question true in this more general setting: given $G\curvearrowright X^n$, is there a point in $Teich(X/G)$ corresponding to a $G$ acting as a subgroup of a Coxeter group?

Comment: Affine conjugation does indeed work in the Euclidean case. The reason similarity conjugation is used in defining Teichmuller space is somewhat subtle, but anyway it was the right conjugation to use in the context of your question (and of our discussion in the comments to follow regarding "realised as").

Comment: However, there is no such thing as "similarity conjugation" or even "affine conjugation" in hyperbolic geometry. The closest thing one finds is "quasiconformal conjugation", which gets you deep into the guts of Teichmuller theory.

Comment: But yes, from an abstract group theoretic point of view, it is true: every discrete, cocompact group of isometries of $\mathbb E^2$ or of $\mathbb H^2$ is isomorphic to a finite index subgroup of some Coxeter group. I suspect you can find a proof of this in [Mike Davis' book](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2013-50-02/S0273-0979-2012-01384-8/S0273-0979-2012-01384-8.pdf).

Comment: Thanks again! I shall have a dig through my copy. Does this generalise to arbitrary dimension do you know?

Comment: Almost certainly not for $\mathbb H^n$ when $n \ge 3$. Even the abstract version is not going to be true. The dimension counting argument doesn't help in that case, because of [Mostow rigidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostow_rigidity_theorem), but there are other invariants one can apply.